# Python Beautiful Soup (Not sure how to parse specific element )

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am not sure how to go about this. I am trying to get the "availability" (True or False) part and the size from the below HTML. They are all located in the very first line.

Each "Availability" is for a specific "size". Is there any way to use beautiful soup to get just the size and availability?

```
{"id":1854781816901,"title":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green","handle":"adidas-originals-x-pharrell-williams-solar-hu-nmd-white-green","description":"\u003cp\u003eCollaboration with\u003cspan\u003e \u003c\/span\u003e\u003cem\u003ePharrell Williams\u003c\/em\u003e\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eHu NMD silhouette\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003ePrimeknit upper\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eBootie-construction\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eTPU side panel stabilizers \u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eCage rope laces\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eFull Boost midsole\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eRugged outsole\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eCo-branded leather heel tabs\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cem\u003e\u003c\/em\u003e \u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eStyle: AAEE7583\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eColor: White \/ Green\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eMaterial: Primeknit\u003c\/p\u003e","published_at":"2018-11-23T05:05:41-05:00","created_at":"2018-11-07T17:52:43-05:00","vendor":"Adidas","type":"Sneakers","tags":["111018fw","111018PW","aaee7583","adidas","adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green","final-sale","footwear","mens","productsize-10","productsize-10-5","productsize-11","productsize-11-5","productsize-12","productsize-13","productsize-7-5","productsize-8","productsize-9-5","sneaker","sneakers","square-footwear"],"price":25000,"price_min":25000,"price_max":25000,"available":true,"price_varies":false,"compare_at_price":0,"compare_at_price_min":0,"compare_at_price_max":0,"compare_at_price_varies":false,"variants":[{"id":17531475427397,"title":"3","option1":"3","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"98165432","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 3","public_title":"3","options":["3"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475460165,"title":"3.5","option1":"3.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"98165433","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 3.5","public_title":"3.5","options":["3.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475492933,"title":"4","option1":"4","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322938","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 4","public_title":"4","options":["4"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475525701,"title":"4.5","option1":"4.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610321788","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 4.5","public_title":"4.5","options":["4.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475558469,"title":"5","option1":"5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323065","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 5","public_title":"5","options":["5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475591237,"title":"5.5","option1":"5.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323058","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 5.5","public_title":"5.5","options":["5.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475624005,"title":"6","option1":"6","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323003","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 6","public_title":"6","options":["6"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475656773,"title":"6.5","option1":"6.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322969","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 6.5","public_title":"6.5","options":["6.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475689541,"title":"7","option1":"7","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610321795","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 7","public_title":"7","options":["7"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475722309,"title":"7.5","option1":"7.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610321764","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 7.5","public_title":"7.5","options":["7.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475787845,"title":"8","option1":"8","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323034","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 8","public_title":"8","options":["8"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475820613,"title":"8.5","option1":"8.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323010","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 8.5","public_title":"8.5","options":["8.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475853381,"title":"9","option1":"9","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322976","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 9","public_title":"9","options":["9"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475886149,"title":"9.5","option1":"9.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322952","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 9.5","public_title":"9.5","options":["9.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475918917,"title":"10","option1":"10","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610321771","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 10","public_title":"10","options":["10"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475951685,"title":"10.5","option1":"10.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323072","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 10.5","public_title":"10.5","options":["10.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475984453,"title":"11","option1":"11","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323027","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 11","public_title":"11","options":["11"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476017221,"title":"11.5","option1":"11.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322990","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 11.5","public_title":"11.5","options":["11.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476082757,"title":"12","option1":"12","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322945","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 12","public_title":"12","options":["12"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476213829,"title":"12.5","option1":"12.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322921","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 12.5","public_title":"12.5","options":["12.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476312133,"title":"13","option1":"13","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323089","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 13","public_title":"13","options":["13"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476344901,"title":"13.5","option1":"13.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323041","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 13.5","public_title":"13.5","options":["13.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476377669,"title":"14","option1":"14","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322983","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 14","public_title":"14","options":["14"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476410437,"title":"14.5","option1":"14.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"98165455","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 14.5","public_title":"14.5","options":["14.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476443205,"title":"15","option1":"15","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"98165456","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 15","public_title":"15","options":["15"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null}],"images":["\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1961.jpg?v=1541803049","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1966.jpg?v=1541803049","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1963.jpg?v=1541803049","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1969.jpg?v=1541803049","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_2002.jpg?v=1541803049"],"featured_image":"\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1961.jpg?v=1541803049","options":["Size"],"content":"\u003cp\u003eCollaboration with\u003cspan\u003e \u003c\/span\u003e\u003cem\u003ePharrell Williams\u003c\/em\u003e\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eHu NMD silhouette\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003ePrimeknit upper\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eBootie-construction\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eTPU side panel stabilizers \u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eCage rope laces\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eFull Boost midsole\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eRugged outsole\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eCo-branded leather heel tabs\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cem\u003e\u003c\/em\u003e \u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eStyle: AAEE7583\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eColor: White \/ Green\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eMaterial: Primeknit\u003c\/p\u003e","shop": {"meganav_image": "\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1961_600x600_crop_center.progressive.jpg?v=1541803049","url": "/products/adidas-originals-x-pharrell-williams-solar-hu-nmd-white-green","product_title": "adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD","product_title_variant": "White / Green"}};


  $(document).on('ready',function(){

    // Add fallback 'max' data attributes to quantites
    $(qtyClass).attr('max',cartMax);
```

Thank you very much, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a common html content,so the Beautifulsoup doesn't work. you can use re module, like this:

```
import re
import json
a="""
{"id":1854781816901,"title":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green","handle":"adidas-originals-x-pharrell-williams-solar-hu-nmd-white-green","description":"\u003cp\u003eCollaboration with\u003cspan\u003e \u003c\/span\u003e\u003cem\u003ePharrell Williams\u003c\/em\u003e\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eHu NMD silhouette\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003ePrimeknit upper\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eBootie-construction\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eTPU side panel stabilizers \u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eCage rope laces\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eFull Boost midsole\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eRugged outsole\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eCo-branded leather heel tabs\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cem\u003e\u003c\/em\u003e \u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eStyle: AAEE7583\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eColor: White \/ Green\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eMaterial: Primeknit\u003c\/p\u003e","published_at":"2018-11-23T05:05:41-05:00","created_at":"2018-11-07T17:52:43-05:00","vendor":"Adidas","type":"Sneakers","tags":["111018fw","111018PW","aaee7583","adidas","adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green","final-sale","footwear","mens","productsize-10","productsize-10-5","productsize-11","productsize-11-5","productsize-12","productsize-13","productsize-7-5","productsize-8","productsize-9-5","sneaker","sneakers","square-footwear"],"price":25000,"price_min":25000,"price_max":25000,"available":true,"price_varies":false,"compare_at_price":0,"compare_at_price_min":0,"compare_at_price_max":0,"compare_at_price_varies":false,"variants":[{"id":17531475427397,"title":"3","option1":"3","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"98165432","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 3","public_title":"3","options":["3"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475460165,"title":"3.5","option1":"3.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"98165433","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 3.5","public_title":"3.5","options":["3.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475492933,"title":"4","option1":"4","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322938","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 4","public_title":"4","options":["4"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475525701,"title":"4.5","option1":"4.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610321788","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 4.5","public_title":"4.5","options":["4.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475558469,"title":"5","option1":"5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323065","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 5","public_title":"5","options":["5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475591237,"title":"5.5","option1":"5.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323058","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 5.5","public_title":"5.5","options":["5.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475624005,"title":"6","option1":"6","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323003","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 6","public_title":"6","options":["6"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475656773,"title":"6.5","option1":"6.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322969","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 6.5","public_title":"6.5","options":["6.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475689541,"title":"7","option1":"7","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610321795","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 7","public_title":"7","options":["7"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475722309,"title":"7.5","option1":"7.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610321764","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 7.5","public_title":"7.5","options":["7.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475787845,"title":"8","option1":"8","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323034","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 8","public_title":"8","options":["8"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475820613,"title":"8.5","option1":"8.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323010","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 8.5","public_title":"8.5","options":["8.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475853381,"title":"9","option1":"9","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322976","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 9","public_title":"9","options":["9"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475886149,"title":"9.5","option1":"9.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322952","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 9.5","public_title":"9.5","options":["9.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475918917,"title":"10","option1":"10","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610321771","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 10","public_title":"10","options":["10"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475951685,"title":"10.5","option1":"10.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323072","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 10.5","public_title":"10.5","options":["10.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531475984453,"title":"11","option1":"11","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323027","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 11","public_title":"11","options":["11"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476017221,"title":"11.5","option1":"11.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322990","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 11.5","public_title":"11.5","options":["11.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476082757,"title":"12","option1":"12","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322945","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 12","public_title":"12","options":["12"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476213829,"title":"12.5","option1":"12.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322921","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 12.5","public_title":"12.5","options":["12.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476312133,"title":"13","option1":"13","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323089","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 13","public_title":"13","options":["13"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476344901,"title":"13.5","option1":"13.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610323041","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 13.5","public_title":"13.5","options":["13.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476377669,"title":"14","option1":"14","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"192610322983","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 14","public_title":"14","options":["14"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476410437,"title":"14.5","option1":"14.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"98165455","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 14.5","public_title":"14.5","options":["14.5"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":17531476443205,"title":"15","option1":"15","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"98165456","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White \/ Green - 15","public_title":"15","options":["15"],"price":25000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null}],"images":["\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1961.jpg?v=1541803049","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1966.jpg?v=1541803049","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1963.jpg?v=1541803049","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1969.jpg?v=1541803049","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_2002.jpg?v=1541803049"],"featured_image":"\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1961.jpg?v=1541803049","options":["Size"],"content":"\u003cp\u003eCollaboration with\u003cspan\u003e \u003c\/span\u003e\u003cem\u003ePharrell Williams\u003c\/em\u003e\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eHu NMD silhouette\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003ePrimeknit upper\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eBootie-construction\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eTPU side panel stabilizers \u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eCage rope laces\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eFull Boost midsole\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eRugged outsole\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eCo-branded leather heel tabs\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e\u003cem\u003e\u003c\/em\u003e \u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eStyle: AAEE7583\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eColor: White \/ Green\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eMaterial: Primeknit\u003c\/p\u003e","shop": {"meganav_image": "\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/White_EE7583_1961_600x600_crop_center.progressive.jpg?v=1541803049","url": "/products/adidas-originals-x-pharrell-williams-solar-hu-nmd-white-green","product_title": "adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD","product_title_variant": "White / Green"}};


  $(document).on('ready',function(){

    // Add fallback 'max' data attributes to quantites
    $(qtyClass).attr('max',cartMax);
"""
text = re.findall('{"id":.*?}',a)
for dic in text:
    availability = json.loads(dic)
    print(availability)
```

you will get all jsons like this:

```
{'id': 17531475427397, 'title': '3', 'option1': '3', 'option2': None, 'option3': None, 'sku': '98165432', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': False, 'name': 'adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White / Green - 3', 'public_title': '3', 'options': ['3'], 'price': 25000, 'weight': 1361, 'compare_at_price': 0, 'inventory_quantity': 0, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}
{'id': 17531475460165, 'title': '3.5', 'option1': '3.5', 'option2': None, 'option3': None, 'sku': '98165433', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': False, 'name': 'adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White / Green - 3.5', 'public_title': '3.5', 'options': ['3.5'], 'price': 25000, 'weight': 1361, 'compare_at_price': 0, 'inventory_quantity': 0, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}
{'id': 17531475492933, 'title': '4', 'option1': '4', 'option2': None, 'option3': None, 'sku': '192610322938', 'requires_shipping': True, 'taxable': True, 'featured_image': None, 'available': False, 'name': 'adidas Originals x Pharrell Williams Solar HU NMD - White / Green - 4', 'public_title': '4', 'options': ['4'], 'price': 25000, 'weight': 1361, 'compare_at_price': 0, 'inventory_quantity': 0, 'inventory_management': 'shopify', 'inventory_policy': 'deny', 'barcode': None}
```

then you can get each "Availability" for a specific "size". but I don't understand the "size".